# Wine fonts problem

Tags: wine, fonts

I installed SumatraPDF with Wine and it works fine but I have problem about fonts. It shows English characters but doesn't shows Georgian. Which font should I install to fix this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you simply using a PDF viewer native to Linux like Evince or Okular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'd tried to install fonts available with ***Winetricks***.

1. Run ***Winetricks***
2. Select your ***wineprefix*** or ***default wineprefix*** if it has used.
3. Select task ***Install a font***
4. Choose needed font package.
5. Wait while package files will be downloaded and installed.
6. Restart your ***wineprefix***

I think the problem can be solved with installing *mscorefonts, unifonts (MS Arial Unicode), tahoma font package* **OR** with installing *allfonts font package*.

But, perhaps it isn't solution for you.
In two words the problem is using Windows-encoded fonts or special fonts installed with SumatraPDF.

Full guide about *manual installing fonts into **Wine*** and *converting fonts with **Fontforge*** you can read here:

http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/Fonts
http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/Fonts#Installing_Windows_Fonts

Comment: How to restart wineprefix?

Comment: If you use **Winetricks** then obvious that a **wineprefix** is an alias for your application under which you run it. Thus for restarting some **wineprefix** you should restart your "Wine app" or "Wine" completely.

Comment: How to restart **Wine**?

Comment: Dead link ; article can now be found at http://wine-wiki.org/index.php/Fonts

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when I use Balsamiq Mockups 3. The font not readable when I renaming the project.

I use this reference to solve this problem: https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

I download the winetricks script

```
cd "${HOME}/Downloads"
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x winetricks
```

Installing cabextract (requirement for installing corefonts with winetricks)

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract
```

And then execute the command

```
sh winetricks corefonts
```

It will installing basic font