# Hebrew fonts in Picasa 3.9 wine 1.4.1 kubuntu 13.10 look as empty squares

Tags: wine, 64-bit, kubuntu, fonts, picasa

I've got a fresh Kubuntu 13.10 64 bit with wine 1.4.1 on it. Fonts seemed to install without a problem (how can I check that? I've installed culmus manually and msfft core with wine). Importing my Albums (not web albums) from my WinXP machine went smoothly except for the fact that album names that have Hebrew letters will show up as empty rectangles (on the left menu bar). If I choose one and right click to *"edit album description"* I can see the Hebrew name just fine.

I've tried the suggestion from *mosestruong* from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=685676) but that only made the letters disappear totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Just copied all of my winXP font library (*c:\windows\fonts\**) to *~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts/* (note the capital F. Not sure if it's a must). a voila! Hebrew Album Names!

Comment: tahoma font solved that problem for me. see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/367373/comments/10)

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to install missing fonts in winetricks

[Wine fonts problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102538/wine-fonts-problem)

1.Run Winetricks.

2.Select your wineprefix or default wineprefix if it has used.

3.Select task Install a font